# How to run async method before render in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have light and dark themes in my app. User selection stored in database (with some other profile data). I want to apply theme before first render. What is happening now - page will be prerendered with light theme and after a few ms changed to dark. This cause a noticeable blinking.

simple page example:

```cs
@page "/"

<div style="background-color: @theme; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <div style="color:orange">Text</div>
</div>

@code {
    private string theme = "white";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // simulate await for a database query;
        theme = "black";
    }
}
```

What have investigated so far.

- If you use "Server" render mode blazor will execute this method once and nothing come to my mind about how to solve it.
- If you use "ServerPrerendered" blazor will execute it 2 times, and for some unclear reasons, first run (out of those 2) is actually awaits database response before sending page to user with correct dark theme. But immediately comes second render and it skip await and display user white page and after a sec (response from database) it change it to dark.

I had an idea to use some sort of cache using "Scoped" dependencies, between those two renders, as it stated "Scoped" lifetime is per a connection (until you F5 refresh a page) but it appear that each those 2 executions have they own "Scope" even I don't specifically refresh.

Another solution i came across is to use synchronous call to database using `.Wait()` or `.Result` it solve the problem of async/await, but i have some doubts about scalability of this  approach.

I would appreciate any other ideas/suggestion.

Comment: Short answer as I don't have time - if you are still stuck let me know and I'll find time later:  Do the async call to fetch the theme in your host cshtml page and pass the theme as a parameter to the root component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Revised answer

The blank flash in the middle is caused by the page refreshing.  The displayed component architecture is actually `App` => `MainLayout` => Index.  `App` and `MainLayout` are refreshing.  To stop the blank flash we need to load the User Settings in `App`.

I've updated `UserSettingsService` for the MudBlazor Dark Theme `bool`:

```cs
public class UserSettingsService
{
    public Task LoadTask { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

    public bool IsDarkTheme { get; private set; } = false;

    public UserSettingsService()
        => LoadTask = GetSettingsAsync();

    private async Task GetSettingsAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        IsDarkTheme = true;
    }
}
```

Add the pre-render stuff to `App`:

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there is nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>

@code {
    [Inject] public UserSettingsService UserSettingsService { get; set; } = default!;

    private bool _initialized;

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Must do this immediately.  This sets the parameters in the component from the supplied ParameterView instance
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            await UserSettingsService.LoadTask;

            _initialized = true;
        }

        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}
```

And then `MainLayout`:

```cs
@inject UserSettingsService UserSettingsService


<MudThemeProvider IsDarkMode=this.UserSettingsService.IsDarkTheme/>
//...
```

### Original answer

First an explanation.

```cs
await Task.Delay(1000); // simulate await for a database query;
```

Yields back to the `base.SetParametersAsync` which runs an initial render (so you can show a "Loading" message).  In your case it renders the page in light mode. What you need to do is do your async Db work before `OnInitializedAsync`.

Here's how I solved a similar problem, applied to your context.

A service to get and manage the User Settings.  This implements an async loader.

```cs
public class UserSettingsService
{
    public string Theme { get; private set; } = "white";

    public Task LoadTask { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;  
    
    public UserSettingsService()
    {
        LoadTask = GetSettingsAsync();
    }

    private async Task GetSettingsAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        this.Theme = "black";
    }
}
```

Registered as:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserSettingsService>();
```

Next a site specific base component, that injects the service and makes sure the data is loaded before any attempt to render.

```cs
public class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] public UserSettingsService UserSettingsService { get; set; } = default!;
    private bool _initialized;

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        // Must do this immediately.  This sets the parameters in the component from the supplied ParameterView instance
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            await this.BeforeInitializedAsync();
            _initialized = true;
        }

        // Call the base to execute the normally lifecycle events but do so with an empty ParameterView as we have already set them
        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }

    // This is our new lifecycle method that makes sure the UserSettingsService
    // has loaded the user setting from the database before the component first renders
    // You could roll this into SetParametersAsync, but I wanted to demonstrate how you can create your own lifecycle methods
    protected virtual async ValueTask BeforeInitializedAsync()
        => await UserSettingsService.LoadTask;
}
```

And Index:

```cs
@page "/"
@inherits MyComponentBase
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div style="background-color: @this.UserSettingsService.Theme; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <div style="color:orange">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. From initial look after i replicated your suggestion, i see kind of similar behavior, but difference is that now instead of "light" page, i see empty page for the same amount of time. As soon as debugger get to await Task.Delay(1000) page become blank until the end of SetParametersAsync method.

Comment: You can't show the "value" i.e. the theme until you've read it from the database.  What do you expect to be displayed while you're getting the settings from the database?

Comment: ServerPrerendered have 2 "passes" to render a page. For the first "pass" it handle await correctly and display prerendered page with correct theme without any blank page. But second "pass" break this because on "await" time it show you blank page. The is no difference in my case do you await in `SetParametersAsync` or inside `OnInitializedAsync`. But technically you right, await inside `SetParametersAsync`` allow to await with the cost of blank page. But does not solve my issue. If you there will be no other suggestions, i will accept this answer a correct one. Thanks!

Comment: Does the Theme apply across the whole application?

Comment: Yes. I do it in MainLayout using MudBlazor theming: https://www.mudblazor.com/customization/overview#dark-palette.

Comment: See revised answer.  I think I've got it!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You nailed it! Actually you have solved even 2 problems: await issue and blank refresh! I am not yet fully understood one about blank refresh, probably I need to learn more about blazor app lifecycle...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the answer to my similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75940915/blazor-fluxor-best-place-to-pre-load-application-state.